# Cannot initialize emoji compact Library, can't find R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs

Tags: android, emoji

So following google's guide I put the dependencies in Gradle
But after that when I try to initialize it with this code.

```
FontRequest fontRequest = new FontRequest(
            "com.google.android.gms.fonts",
            "com.google.android.gms",
            "Noto Color Emoji Compat",
            R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs);
```

The last line is what is wrong , I don't have any such array so Android studio cant resolve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create an XML file called `font_certs.xml` in your `values` folder and copy the content of this file [here](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/blob/master/DownloadableFontsKotlin/app/src/main/res/values/font_certs.xml) of Google sample.

This is the content in case the link will be moved:

```
<resources>
    <array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
        <item>@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_dev</item>
        <item>@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_prod</item>
    </array>
    <string-array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_dev">
        <item>
            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
        </item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_prod">
        <item>
            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
        </item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then you can use `R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs` in your code to download Google fonts.

Comment: AWESOME, thankyou so much, i've watched so many tutorials but none of them mentioned this even once.
You are  a life saver.